# Can you support through ships in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thones*, one can send attacking troops to a distant region in one order with a chain of ships.  Does this also apply to support orders?

That is, can I support a combat with land troops in an otherwise non-adjacent region if I can connect the two regions with ships?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely not! Quite apart from the fact that that makes no sense whatsoever, it also explicitly states that you can't on page 23 of the rulebook (bottom right).

> While land areas connected by ship transport are considered adjacent
>   for purposes of marching and retreating, they are **not** considered
>   adjacent for any other purpose (including supporting and raiding).

Comment: Correct! It's worth noting that the ship itself, however, can support an adjacent land territory.